# Dompdf Version 0.8.5 Arabic RTL Not Showing Correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, utf-8, dompdf

I'm currently using the latest version of dompdf 0.8.5 , trying to export arabic text to pdf file

```
<?php

$linktentinvoice='<html><head><style>*{ font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }</style><head><p>مرحبا</p></html>';

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($linktentinvoice, 'UTF-8');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

The result is showing : ا ب ح ر م

However the result has to be: مرحبا

Answer (score 0):

The UTF-8 codes for those two Arabic strings are the same, but in the opposite order.  Here's the hex:

```
D985 D8B1 D8AD D8A8 D8A7  == ا ب ح ر م
D8A7 D8A8 D8AD D8B1 D985  == مرحبا
```

*Somewhere*, *something* is failing to understand that Arabic is "right-to-left".

Suggest you get hex dumps at various steps of the processing.

I believe that MySQL is *not* at fault.  (But I can't say about the other components.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to display correctly in a PDF character shaping has to be performed by the rendering engine. Dompdf (up to and including 0.8.6) does not fully support rendering of Arabic script (see [issue #712](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/712)).

One work-around would be to perform the necessary conversion of your text prior to feeding it to Dompdf. In the issue the developer of [ar-php](https://github.com/khaled-alshamaa/ar-php) suggests the following:

```
require_once './ar-php/src/arabic.php';
$Arabic = new ArPHP\I18N\Arabic();

$p = $Arabic->arIdentify($html);

for ($i = count($p)-1; $i >= 0; $i-=2) {
    $utf8ar = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs(substr($html, $p[$i-1], $p[$i] - $p[$i-1]));
    $html   = substr_replace($html, $utf8ar, $p[$i-1], $p[$i] - $p[$i-1]);
}
```

You can then render the modified HTML content via Dompdf.